# How do I delete users from my MongoDB on my meteor.js web application

Tags: javascript, mongodb, web, mongodb-query

I developed a web app using meteor.js and I can view my users on my command prompt, but how do I delete users?

I tried

`meteor mongo myapp.meteor.com`
`db.users.remove({_id:<user id>});`

but I got an error

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

I tried it without the `<>`

but I also got an error

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Then, I tried

`db.users.remove('USER_ID');`

but I got this error -_-

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Could anyone give me any guidance? And just out of curiosity, is there a website where I can view my MongoDB for my meteor web app and delete users from there?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
db.users.remove({_id: 'USER_ID'});
```

EDIT:

From the Mongo documentation for the collection's remove function (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/remove-documents/) you can see that the function accepts a selector which is an object of the properties matching those documents that should be deleted. Since the _id property is guaranteed to be unique within a collection, a single document at most will be removed when the above is executed.

Comment: The answer is appreciated, but it would be useful if you could go into more detail on why you believe this should work!

Comment: @gpicazo So on the website the user created a post, and when I delete the user, his posts don't go away? How would I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
db.collection('MY_COLLECTION').findOneAndDelete({_id: 'USER_ID'});
```